# Angular not entering custom form validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a password match validation in a register form, but Angular never enters the custom validation, and I cannot seem to figure out why. The form is as follows.

```js
this.userSettingsForm = this.fb.group({
  username: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4)
    ]
  ],
  password: [''],
  password_confirm: ['']
},
{
  Validator: this.passwordMatchValidator
});
```

The validation function is the following;

```js
passwordMatchValidator() {
  const password = this.userSettingsForm.get('password').value;
  const confirmPassword = this.userSettingsForm.get('password_confirm').value;

  if(password.errors && !confirmPassword.errors.passwordMatchValidator) {
    return;
  }

  if(password !== confirmPassword) {
    confirmPassword.setErrors({ notSame: true});
  }
  else {
    confirmPassword.setErrors(null);
  }
}
```

Using the following to display errors

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="userSettingsForm.controls.password_confirm.errors">
  {{ userSettingsForm.controls.password_confirm.errors.message }}
</ng-container>
```

But the form always submits as valid. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are using `Validator` instead of `validators` where you are declaring your custom validator in the form.

Then we need to properly call the validation function, also I suggest you actually put the error on the form group itself, but that is perhaps just a preference. Anyway, I suggest the following:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.userSettingsForm = this.fb.group(
    {
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      password_confirm: ['', Validators.required]
    },
    { validators: this.passwordMatchValidator() } // should be "validators"
  );
}
```

and the validator I suggest this:

```ts
passwordMatchValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (form: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const password = form.get('password').value;
    const confirmPassword = form.get('password_confirm').value;
    return password === confirmPassword ? null : { notSame: true };
  };
}
```

Then you can display the error with `userSettingsForm.hasError('notSame')`

A **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1dwpxw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)** for reference.

Comment: I made these changes. But it still does not fix the issue! The form is always passed as valid on submitting.

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve], you can make a stackblitz that shows your issue, as we can see in the stackblitz that this code works. So the issue must be somewhere in your code.

Comment: Your stackblitz has the same issue. Form is still considered valid and submittable. Only difference to my code is that the button contains [disabled]="!userSettingsForm.valid"

Comment: Well I added to the button that it is disabled if the form is not valid. Was that your issue? Disabling the button?

Comment: You can now see that you cannot submit the form when the form is invalid.

Comment: No. I have that in my code, but it never disables. I compared the code over and over and cannot find any differences.

Comment: Then please create a stackblitz that reproduces your issue. Otherwise cannot help, as it obviously works in the stackblitz I created.

Comment: I tried to create one. Hope this works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-hw5jup?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Well, the stackblitz didn't run, as you might have noticed. Looking at the code though, you are using `Validators` instead of `validators` when declaring the custom validator. Please reread my answer!